# Seeking Assistance with Reading Emails from Office 365

Tags: email, office365, office365api

I have been facing challenges when it comes to reading emails from Office 365. It seems that the content I come across is frequently deprecated, making it difficult to keep up with the ever-changing integration requirements set by Microsoft. It feels as if they expect us to have an abundance of time to constantly update our software and stay in sync with their updates.

Is anyone aware of a reliable blog or resource that provides continuous updates on reading emails from Office 365. I am in search of a blog that is maintained and regularly updated, ensuring that I can stay informed about the latest developments and seamlessly update our software accordingly.

Thank you

Comment: Take a look at the Graph API, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/ for more information.

Comment: Have you registered your app with Azure. Which access mode are you using?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts

And yes, Graph API is the way to go:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/mail-api-overview

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get something going using information gleamed from the below url:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-authenticate-an-ews-application-by-using-oauth

I have previously created and enabled the Azure App through the Azure Portal, and given the app a number of API permissions which allowed me to Access and Read emails from an Outlook 365 Mailbox.

[List of Permissions granted to App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oPCKN.png)

I am sure that some of these permissions are 'extra', but will have to better identify which is required, and which is superfluous, in later revisions.

What I was also missing, in my previous attempts, are the below X-AnchorMailbox and Impersonation:

```
    ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
      new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, Secrets.email_address);

    //Include x-anchormailbox header
    ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", Secrets.email_address);
```

---

### Find the complete Read Unread Emails code below:

```
    static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ReadUnreadEmails(string[] args)
    {
        // Using Microsoft.Identity.Client 4.22.0
        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(Secrets.client_id)
            .WithClientSecret(Secrets.client_secret)
            .WithTenantId(Secrets.tenant_id)
            .Build();

        var ewsScopes = new string[] { "https://outlook.office365.com/.default" };

        try
        {
            var authResult = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(ewsScopes)
                .ExecuteAsync();

            // Configure the ExchangeService with the access token
            var ewsClient = new ExchangeService();
            ewsClient.Url = new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
            ewsClient.Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(authResult.AccessToken);
            ewsClient.ImpersonatedUserId =
                new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, Secrets.email_address);

            //Include x-anchormailbox header
            ewsClient.HttpHeaders.Add("X-AnchorMailbox", Secrets.email_address);

            //// Make an EWS call
            //var folders = ewsClient.FindFolders(WellKnownFolderName.MsgFolderRoot, new FolderView(10));
            //foreach (var folder in folders.Folders) { Console.WriteLine($"Folder: {folder.DisplayName}"); }

            FolderId fid = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
            Folder inbox = Folder.Bind(ewsClient, fid);

            SearchFilter sf = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.IsRead, false));

            FindItemsResults<Item> items = inbox.FindItems(sf, new ItemView(100));

            var sorted = items.OrderBy(o => o.DateTimeReceived);

            foreach ( var email in sorted )
            {
                if(  !email.HasAttachments ) continue;

                //READ ATTACHMENTS HERE
            }//foreach
        }//try
        catch (MsalException ex) { Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}"); throw; }//catch
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine($"Error acquiring access token: {ex}"); throw; }//catch
    }//ReadUnreadEmails
```